# Disable Bluetooth discoverability in Redmi 6 / MIUI 11

Tags: miui, redmi, mi

Is it possible to completely turn of the ability of my Redmi 6 (using MIUI 11 currently) to being discovered via Bluetooth by other devices? If yes, then how to achieve this?

Things I've tried or read so far:

- No corresponding system option (NFUI clone on my Neffos X9 still has it)
- [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218122/20449) that is reported to not work under MIUI 10 so won't work most likely under MIUI 11
- Turning off [Bluetooth Scanning](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/csc99i/turn_off_bluetooth_visibility/) (turned off, no effect, device still discoverable)
- Using [Bluetooth Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.bluetoothsettings&gl=AT) 3rd party application

I had the biggest faith in last option (Bluetooth Settings app), but it fails completely under Readmi 6 / MIUI 11. Not only Bluetooth discoverability is turned on again when phone is restarted or Bluetooth is enabled, as it is written [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218122/20449).

It is also turned on again when any paired device connects to it or when Bluetooth Settings app is reopened again. So this is a completely false pathway.

Answer (score 2):

Found the "[[Tools] MIUI Bluetooth Discovery App](https://c.mi.com/thread-2162720-1-1.html)" thread in Mi Community. It lead me to [Bluetooth Visibility Fix app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.minol.miuibluetoothfix) which seems to be working as expected under MIUI 11 / Readmi 6 phone.

There's some work when start using it:

- It is a  system service that needs special permissions to auto-start,
- It didn't work ("restarted" itself to "Visible to all") for first 2-3 times then it suddenly started to work.

But after some time it does seems to be resolving the issue in question and turning off Bluetooth discoverability permanently.

In case the Bluetooth Visibility Fix app is not working for you itself, the "[[Tools] MIUI Bluetooth Discovery App](https://c.mi.com/thread-2162720-1-1.html)" article also mentions some user-contributed app, available as direct .apk file download under above link. Consider it as an alternative.